# How do I increase the font size of the table?

Tags: tables, fonts, resize

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx,makecell}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\setcitestyle{numbers}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}   
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
    

  
  \caption{SURVEY OF RELEVANT LITERATURE}
  \label{tab:yourtablelabel}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{8}
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}
  {
  \begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|m|}
    \hline
   \centering Ref & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Technology} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Applications} & Highlights \\
    \hline
         & Finite Element Method & Surrogate Modeling & Reservoir Computing & AR/VR &  SVM ML algorithm & Haptic Feedback & TENG Sensors & CFD & Healthcare \& biomedical & Manufacturing \& industry & Aerospace \& space & Agriculture \& Environment monitoring & \\ \hline
    
   \centering \cite{c8} & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark  & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & This paper discusses the use of reservoir computing in DT-SR technology \\ \hline
   \centering \cite{c9} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & This paper discusses the use of triboelectric nanogenerator sensors for DT-SR merge
 \\ \hline
    
   \centering \cite{c79} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This paper describes using ML algorithms for
    accurate and predictive digital twin models of soft robots \\ \hline

    
  \centering \cite{c99} & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This paper describes how  \\ \hline
    
   \centering \cite{c167} & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This study describes how augmented reality can be used in assistance with machine learning algorithms to create DT models of soft robots \\ \hline

   \centering \cite{c168} & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This study describes how augmented reality can be used in assistance with machine learning algorithms to create DT models of soft robots \\ \hline
      
 \centering \cite{c169} & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & This study discusses the use of AR and ML algorithms for the creation of soft robot DTs \\ \hline
    
  \centering  \cite{c76} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & This study discusses all the up-to-date technologies encompassing DT-SR integration \\ \hline
    
   \centering \cite{c170} & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & x & This paper covers the use of AR, ML and Teng sensors in the revolution of DT-SR technology \\ \hline
    
   \centering Current Study & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & This study discusses all the up-to-date technologies encompassing DT-SR integration \\ \hline
    %Row 1, Cell 1 & Row 1, Cell 2 & Row 1, Cell 3 \\
  \end{tabular}
 }
    
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Latex Table]

Comment: Your example demonstrates perfectly why you should never use `\resizebox` for elements which contain text

Comment: How do I fix this? What should I use instead of \resizebox?

Comment: Off-topic: Don't load packages more than once (e.g., `rotating`); don't load packages that conflict with each other (e.g., `cite` and `natbib`); and don't load packages that are loaded automatically by other packages you also load (e.g., `amsfonts`). And, don't use all-caps for the argument of `\caption`, as the `IEEEtran` document class is set to use small-caps by default for captions.

Answer (score 5):

Never use `\resizebox` for elements which contain text. The results are awful!

Instead:

- use a smaller font size for your table
- don't add tons of additional space using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{8}`
- use a fixed width column for your last column so you get text with line breaks instead of having your very long texts all in one line
- don't use vertical lines, they look very amateurish

---

A suggestion to get you started, you will have to improve the line breaking in the header:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularray}    
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}
\caption{SURVEY OF RELEVANT LITERATURE}
\footnotesize
\begin{tblr}{
  cells={halign=c,valign=m},
  colsep = 2mm,
  colspec={XXXXXXXXXXXXX[2]X[5,halign=l]}
}
  \toprule
  \SetCell[r=2]{} Ref & \SetCell[c=8]{} Technology & &&&&&&&\SetCell[c=4]{} Applications & Highlights &&&\\
  \cmidrule[r]{2-9}\cmidrule[l]{10-13}
  & Finite Element Method & Surrogate Modeling & Reservoir Computing & AR/VR & SVM~ML algorithm & Haptic Feedback & TENG Sensors & CFD & Health\-care \& biomedical & Manu\-facturing \& industry & Aerospace \& space & Agriculture \& Environment monitoring & \\ 
  \midrule
  \cite{c8} & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark  & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & This paper discusses the use of reservoir computing in DT-SR technology \\ 
  \cite{c9} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & This paper discusses the use of triboelectric nanogenerator sensors for DT-SR merge
  \\ 
  \cite{c79} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This paper describes using ML algorithms for
  accurate and predictive digital twin models of soft robots \\    
  \cite{c99} & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This paper describes how  \\ 
  \cite{c167} & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This study describes how augmented reality can be used in assistance with machine learning algorithms to create DT models of soft robots \\ 
  \cite{c168} & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This study describes how augmented reality can be used in assistance with machine learning algorithms to create DT models of soft robots \\ 
  \cite{c169} & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & This study discusses the use of AR and ML algorithms for the creation of soft robot DTs \\ 
  \cite{c76} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & This study discusses all the up-to-date technologies encompassing DT-SR integration \\ 
  \cite{c170} & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & x & This paper covers the use of AR, ML and Teng sensors in the revolution of DT-SR technology \\ Current Study & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & This study discusses all the up-to-date technologies encompassing DT-SR integration \\ 
  \bottomrule
  %Row 1, Cell 1 & Row 1, Cell 2 & Row 1, Cell 3 \\
\end{tblr}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @nowshint You're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

I would also recommend that you *not* use the `\resizebox` sledgehammer. Instead, I suggest you employ a `tabularx` environment and allow automatic line breaking in all cells. Furthermore, I'd get rid of all vertical lines and use far fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor,makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

% new code:
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}\hsize=0.9\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\hsize=2.0\hsize}X}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength{\mylen}{\textheight}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\caption{Survey of Relevant Literature}
\label{tab:yourtablelabel}

\begin{tabularx}{\mylen}{@{} l CCCc CCCc CCCC L @{}}
\toprule
Ref & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Technology} 
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Applications} 
    & This study discusses \dots \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
    & Finite Element Method & Surrogate Modeling & Reservoir Computing & AR/VR 
    & SVM ML algorithm & Haptic Feedback & TENG Sensors & CFD 
    & Healthcare \& biomedical & Manufacturing \& industry & Aerospace \& space & Agriculture \& Environment monitoring 
    & \\ 
\midrule
    
\cite{c8} & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & the use of reservoir computing in DT-SR technology \\ 
\addlinespace
\cite{c9} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & the use of triboelectric nanogenerator sensors for DT-SR merge \\ 
\addlinespace
\cite{c79} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & using ML algorithms for accurate and predictive digital twin models of soft robots \\ 
\addlinespace
\cite{c99} & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & This paper describes how \dots \\ 
\addlinespace   
\cite{c167} & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & augmented reality can be used in assistance with machine learning algorithms to create DT models of soft robots \\ 
\addlinespace
\cite{c168} & x & x & x & \checkmark & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & how augmented reality can be used in assistance with machine learning algorithms to create DT models of soft robots \\ 
\addlinespace
\cite{c169} & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & the use of AR and ML algorithms for the creation of soft robot DTs \\ 
\addlinespace    
\cite{c76} & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & x & x & all the up-to-date technologies encompassing DT-SR integration \\ 
\addlinespace    
\cite{c170} & x & x & x & x & x & x & x & \checkmark & x & \checkmark & x & x & the use of AR, ML and Teng sensors in the revolution of DT-SR technology \\ 
\addlinespace 
\makecell{Current\\Study} & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & all up-to-date technologies encompassing DT-SR integration \\ 
\bottomrule
%Row 1, Cell 1 & Row 1, Cell 2 & Row 1, Cell 3 \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```